# For loop converting NA in factor variables into "None"

Tags: r

I want to convert the NAs in my factor variables into a string "None" that will be a level in my data set.

i have tried

```
for ( col in 1:ncol(data)){
  class(data$col) == "factor"
  data$col = addNA(data$col)
  levels(data$col) <- c(levels(data$col), "None")
  print(summary(data))
}
```

And i got this error

```
Unknown or uninitialised column: `col`.Unknown or uninitialised column: `col`.Error: Assigned data `addNA(cdata$col)` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 1000 rows.
x Assigned data has 0 rows.
i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
```

**What is the problem in this way?**
**What is the better way to do this for all factor columns at once rather that doing each column alone.**

Answer (score 1):

We can loop `across` the columns that are `factor`, convert the `NA` to "None" using `fct_explicit_na` from `forcats`

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
data <- data %>%
     mutate(across(where(is.factor), ~ fct_explicit_na(., na_level = "None")))
```

---

In the `for` loop, there are multiple issues

1. `class(data$col) == "factor"` is checked, but it should be inside an `if(...)` expression
2. `data$col` - is wrong as there are no column names with `col` as name, instead it would be `data[[col]]`
3. `summary(data)` can be checked outside the `for` loop

```
for (col in seq_along(data)){
  if(class(data[[col]]) == "factor") {
     data[[col]] = addNA(data[[col]])
     levels(data[[col]]) <- c(levels(data[[col]]), "None")    
   }
}

print(summary(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way:

1. identify which columns are factor
2. Add "None" to the levels of each factor
3. Replace NA's by "None":

Here is an example with a mock dataset:

```
# identify which is factor column
x <-  sapply(df, is.factor) 

df[, x] <- lapply(df[, x], function(.){
    levels(.) <- c(levels(.), "None")
    replace(., is.na(.), "None")
})
```

output:

```
  a     b         c
  <fct> <fct> <dbl>
1 1     None      2
2 None  3        NA
3 4     None     NA
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(a = structure(c(1L, NA, 2L), .Label = c("1", "4"
), class = "factor"), b = structure(c(NA, 1L, NA), .Label = "3", class = "factor"), 
c = c(2, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```